# Springboot+Oauth Client Credential Grant Flow with Azure AD

Tags: azure, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to protect my API (springboot+java) using Client Credential Grant flow with Azure AD as Authorization Server.
I have looked the internet but the examples I am finding is resource and authorization server in springboot.
Does anyone has any samples of how to secure API with Client Credential Grant Flow using Java Springboot and Azure AD?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The Authorization Server is the Microsoft identity platform endpoint, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#the-basics). Not sure what "Azure AD as Authorization Server" means?

Comment: I want Azure AD to provide access token.

Comment: You want to authenticate in Azure AD using 'username + password', then, if authentication succeeded, you generate a token in Java, or you want the Azure AD to generate the token for you?

Comment: I want Azure AD to generate the token. I want authentication with clientId and clientsecret. Server to server interaction without user intervention I want

Answer (score 0):

We use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get access token with the following steps. The access token is provided by Azure AD.

[image]

Try this [sample](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/02/client-creds-with-spring-boot) with `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails`.

Comment: The way they are using Okta to register the application for setting Authorization Server, I want example where I can register my application with Azure AD instead and develop my Resource Server and Client in Springboot.